# Access property set with setProperty from QML

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I've got a subclass of `QObject` and use `setProperty` to add dynamic properties to it in C++.

Now I want to use them in QML. I would have expected to be able to access them like properties defined with `Q_PROPERTY` but that only yields `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible. As a possible workaround you can expose from your C++ object to QML some helper function to get the value of a dynamic property:

```cpp
TestObject::TestObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    setProperty("test","testvalue");
}

QVariant TestObject::getDynamicProperty(const QString &name)
{
    return property(name.toLatin1());
}
```

and so you will be able to get its value from QML:

```js
TestObject {
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(getDynamicProperty("test"));
}
```